# File being uploaded as part of a form isn't part of the request in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

A form I have created includes an upload field to upload a file with. This file can be any format. The form itself is created inside a FormType, and a controller handles the submission of the form successfully. However, every time I submit the form to this controller and I do a `print_r` or `var_dump()`, the upload field isn't included as part of the params of the POST request. When I use `$file = $request->files->get('estimateUpload');` and `var_dump()` that it will only ever return `NULL`.

Here is the formType that I am using:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\IhcVehicleDamageMatrix;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

class IhcVehicleDamageEntryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('incidentId')
            ->add('vehicleDamageId')
            ->add('damageType')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('wheelTyreDamage')
            ->add('tyreAge')
            ->add('tyreDotCode')
            ->add('treadDepth')
            ->add('renumerationCost')
            ->add('itemAge')
            ->add('created')
            ->add('modified')
            ->add('estimateUpload', FileType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => IhcVehicleDamageMatrix::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the view file this is how I am using the upload field:

```
{{ form_start(damageForm, {'action': path('forms_ihc_damage_details_submitform'), 'method': 'POST', 'attr': {'id': 'ihcFormDamageDetails', 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}}) }}
{{ form_row(damageForm._token) }}
                    <tr>
                        <th>Upload Estimate</th>
                        <td>
                            {{ form_widget(damageForm.estimateUpload) }}
                            <small>{{ form_help(damageForm.estimateUpload) }}</small>
                            <div class="form-error">
                                {{ form_errors(damageForm.estimateUpload) }}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
{{ form_errors(damageForm) }}
{{ form_end(damageForm, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

And in the controller, this is how I am getting the form data:

```
    public function vehicleDamageForm(Request $request)
    {
        // Get Form Details
        $formdet = $request->get('ihc_vehicle_damage_entry');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $file = $request->files->get('estimateUpload');
        var_dump($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to get `estimateUpload` directly from `IhcVehicleDamageMatrix`. Try something like this inside controller:

```
$ihcVehicleDamageMatrix = new IhcVehicleDamageMatrix();

$form = $this->createForm(IhcVehicleDamageEntryType::class, $ihcVehicleDamageMatrix);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $file = $ihcVehicleDamageMatrix->estimateUpload();
    dump($file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this was one of the first things I tried and the file is still returned as `NULL` for some reason. I took what you provided, amended it as there were typos, and included the `$request` and it provides `NULL`.

Comment: Are you render form element with `form_start` twig function? It looks like you don't have multipart/form-data enctype.

Comment: I am. I've updated my question with the beginning and end of the form.

Comment: Maybe check Symfony Profiler to see if you even have this file in `$_FILES` PHP global variable after submitting form with selected file.

Comment: In order to look at the Profiler, I had to take off some Ajax that I use in order to submit the form. When I did that and it just submitted normally the file appeared! So it's the ajax thing that is causing issues with this now, not symfony itself.